# commutative Noetherian ring whose every maximal ideal is projective

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, noetherian, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. If every maximal ideal of $R$ is projective as an $R$-module, then is $R$ [hereditary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_ring)?